# Pass file as an argument to visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, file-io

I try to debug a program in VS2010. In Windows PowerShell I type`./Nbody.exe ./config.txt`. But, when I enter `.\config.txt` or other forms of it in the Command Argument form Debugging section from Property Manager window it seems that my program cannot find the file. In fact this part of my code respond:

`ifstream CSVfile(CSVFileName);`

```
if (CSVfile == NULL) {
    cout << "ERROR: Cannot Open CSV file" << endl;
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [full example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: stating the obvious but try providing the full path.It can save you in case you change the exe location but forget to copy the txt.

Comment: Entering .\config.txt assumes that the file is in the working directory.  The default working directory is $(ProjectDir).  Does $(ProjectDir)\config.txt exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual studio calcutates relative paths starting at `working dir` path. So, you have to use visual studio variables as `$(ProjectDir)` to compound the paths of your files.

Something like: `$(ProjectDir)\config.txt`, otherwise you have to set the path relative to `working dir` path.

Let's say your structure is this:

```
project_name
    + project_name
    | project_name.sln
    | debug
        | project_name.exe
        | config.txt
    + ipch
```

and you have `.\project_name\project_name` as working directory.

The path you enter in the project configuration for debugging has to be relative to the `working dir`:

```
..\debug\config.txt
```

**Update**

As @Goku states in his (I'm assuming Goku is a 'he', :) ) comment:

> For VS2017, `$(ProjectDir)` already contained a '\' concatenated on the directory name.

Comment: I checked it, sln file was in the "project name" directory, which contains debug,ipch and "project name" directories. Working directory was set to second "project name" directory! So I should go back to reach to the debug folder which contains .txt file.

Comment: I think this is because I am writing a CUDA program. :)

Comment: For me (using Visual studio 2017), I didn't need the '\' in $(ProjectDir)\config.txt since $(ProjectDir) already contained a '\\' concatenated on the directory name

Comment: @Goku Can you tell if that is new to VS 2017?

Comment: @RaydelMiranda no idea, due to the "information assurance" group I only am allowed to have VS2017 on this machine

Comment: @Goku Ok, anyway I'll update the answer with your comment. Thanks.